# How to break up C-Functions without increasing stacksize

Tags: c, refactoring, inline, compiler-optimization, stack-size

Working in embedded Systems design, I am often confronted with Legacy Code, where somebody wrote some ISR which consists of a huge if/else-Jungle, sometimes spanning multiple screen-lengths. Now, trying to be a good programmer I try to refactor the function, using the paradigms I learned, one of them being: "A function should do one thing only".

So I break down the function into multiple static sub-function, which have descriptive names and encapsulate variables. But since I am working on an embedded device, I need to be considerate of stacksize and the number of jumps (especially in an ISR that might get called often and might itself get interrupted by something else).

Now, of cause most(or even all) Compilers can be forced to inline a function (as __always_inline does with gcc). But even that increases stacksize, if I have to pass parameters (they do not necessarily get optimized away), even if it is just a few bytes per parameter.

Now for my actual question: **Is there a way not to increase stacksize while breaking up functions in C?**

**EDIT:**
To make my Question clearer: Here is an Example of some Code, where I just shifted some of the code to inline-functions.

Static stack usage is 144 without inline-functions and 160 with inline functions.

Original:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  char inputString[100];
  scanf("%s",inputString);

  static char delimiterArray[] = {' ','+','-','/','*','='};
  for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(inputString); i++){
    printf("%c",inputString[i]);

    char* inputChar = inputString + i;
    for(int j = 0; j<sizeof(delimiterArray);j++){
      if( *inputChar == delimiterArray[j]){
        printf("DELIMITER: %c",delimiterArray[j]);
      }
      if(inputString[i] == '\0'){
        printf("\nNuberOfChars: %d\n",i);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

With inline-functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static inline void checkForDelimiters(char* inputChar)__attribute__((always_inline));
static inline void decomposeString(char* inputString)__attribute__((always_inline));

int main(){

  char inputString[100];
  scanf("%s",inputString);
  decomposeString(inputString);

  return 0;
}

static void checkForDelimiters(char* inputChar){
  static char delimiterArray[] = {' ','+','-','/','*','='};
  for(int j = 0; j<sizeof(delimiterArray);j++){
    if(*inputChar == delimiterArray[j]){
      printf("DELIMITER: %c",delimiterArray[j]);
    }
  }
}

static void decomposeString(char* inputString){

  for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(inputString); i++){
    printf("%c",inputString[i]);
    checkForDelimiters(inputString+i);

    if(inputString[i] == '\0'){
      printf("\nNuberOfChars: %d\n",i);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can break it up into functions but minimize stack by reducing the number of levels in your "call function hierarchy" (a "who calls who" tree).

Comment: Use `static` sub-functions. The compiler will inline static functions which are called only once.

Comment: making inline functions increases the performance as well as reduces the use of stack. Why do you think inline functions increase the stack size?

Comment: Of cause inline functions reduce stacksize compared to non-inline functions. My Question is about breaking up code into several inline functions, that were not functions beforehand. So it's about the comparison of inline-functions to plain code.
As a matter of fact, if you write some lines of code and just move some of that code into inline-functions (which by my intuition should not make any difference what-so-ever, the stack-usage differs slightly. I included an example into the original question.